# Are more S boxes more secure in a SP-Network?

Tags: s-boxes

The classic DES uses 8 different fixed S boxes.  If computer memory was not an issue, would say 800 different S boxes be more secure?  I'm thinking of a SP-network that would only run on a server like computer, and not have to be ported to smaller things like smart cards.  Is more better?

Might it mean fewer rounds of processing were required for a given level of security?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why AES (for example) wouldn't work for you?  Why do you think you need to invent your own cipher?  The fact that you have to ask this question would indicate to me that you aren't qualified to do so.

Comment: 1) The increased pressure on the CPU cache might be more expensive than what you gain from being able to reduce the number of rounds. 2) You can't add special s-box instructions to the CPU if there are many sboxes (see AES-NI)

Comment: poncho, am I at least qualified to ask the question..?  It's not for a cipher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More s-boxes are not necessarily better. Due to hardware complexity restrictions, and the structure of the permutation, DES needed multiple small s-boxes. A single small s-box would have been too weak, and larger s-boxes require substantially more hardware resources. The specific requirements for the cipher lead them to use 8 different s-boxes, and with the help of the NSA, order them in a very specific way.

There are only so many small s-boxes with good properties, 800 DES style s-boxes in a cipher would probably not be a good idea; the security to complexity ratio would be very undesirable.

The next level is a larger s-box. Larger s-boxes allow substantially more nonlinearity, at the expense of substantially higher computational resources. An 8-bit s-box takes up $2^8$ values each 8-bits in size; a 16-bit s-box takes up $2^{16}$ values each 16-bits in size, which is 512 times larger, but much less linear.

There are also s-boxes with output sizes larger than the input size, such as those used in Twofish. 8-bit x 32-bit s-boxes are notably used in Twofish and Blowfish, and many other ciphers. Having the output be at least twice as large as the input allows constructions with better nonlinear properties than if they were the same size, while keeping the total complexity of the s-box within a reasonable size.